# Show different div, based on device or OS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html5-video

Is that somehow possible?

Reason:

I have a video (video.js player), that I want to autoplay on desktop and iphone. However, android devices are having trouble with autoplay, hence I want to show them a version of the video that is not set on autoplay.

Comment: Could you share some more information, e.g. how do you generate the page, what js libs are in there, do you expect a server-side or client-side solution...

Comment: This is a job for JavaScript, not CSS or HTML.

Comment: You probably have to use something like jquery-mobile or similar -  http://www.csillamker.hu/webaruhaz/pdf/index.php?q=jquery-mobile-detect-device-type